# VBA How to handle an error when setting a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro to look at the headings in one sheet and the headings in another to copy the data over, but not all the headings are in the second sheet which is causing a block variable not set error. I've been trying to factor in an error check to get it to skip the value if empty but it refuses to play. TD and RawData are global variables. My code is below:

````
Dim FromCol As Integer
Dim ToCol As Integer
Dim RawRows As Integer
Dim TDCols As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim element As Variant

'set variables
RawRows = (RawData.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row) - 1
TDCols = TD.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim colArray(200) As String

For i = 2 To (TDCols + 1)
    colArray(i) = TD.Cells(1, i).Value
Next i

'Copy Data
For Each element In colArray
        FromCol = RawData.Range("1:1").Find(element, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        ToCol = TD.Range("1:1").Find(element, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column

        For i = 2 To (RawRows + 1)
            TD.Cells(i, ToCol).Value = RawData.Cells(i, FromCol).Value
        Next i
Next element

End Sub```
````

Answer (score 5):

The error is a result of the way you use `Find`.

When you do this...

```
RawRows = (RawData.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row) - 1
```

You are directly reading the row number of the ***range*** returned by `Find`.  This is a problem when there isn't a match because the returned range is literally `Nothing`.  You can't get a row number from nothing; and thus, your error.

To avoid the error, you must `Set` the returned range to a range variable, test the variable for `Nothing`, and only read the row if the variable is not `Nothing`.

```
Sub YourSub()
    Dim findInSheet As Worksheet
    Dim findResult As Range
    Dim rowNumber As Long
     [...]
    Set findResult = findInSheet.Range.Find( [...] )
    If Not findResult Is Nothing Then  'a match was found
        rowNumber = findResult.Row
         [...]
    Else  'a match was not found
       [...] 
    End If
     [...]
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ This becomes a better answer after the "edit" :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Yeah, I'm one of 'those' people that make a few dozen edits before a post becomes half-decent... And thrice that number when editing via mobile.