# Applying code to active workbook from another workbook error: No such a interface supported

Tags: excel, vba

I want below code to open a closed workbook and copy the values from the range StartRow and EndRow to active workbook.

I get

> error 1004  "No such interface supported".

on line  `"xlBook.Sheets(ShName).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 1)).Select"`

When I run this code directly in the workbook I want to copy the data from, it works.

```
Sub GetDataFromClosedBook()

'copy data from closed workbook to active workbook

Dim xlApp As Application
Dim xlBook As Workbook
Dim sh As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Path source Wokrbook
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\name\Desktop\EXCEL USEFUL DOSC\Missing Data Check New Process\Missing Data Reports\" & Sheets("Data Check").Range("C3").Value & ".xlsx")

xlApp.Visible = True

ShName = Sheets("Data Check").Range("C3").Value

With xlBook.Sheets(ShName)

    StartRow = .Range("E:E").Find(what:="January-2020", after:=.Range("E1")).Row
    EndRow = .Range("E:E").Find(what:="January-2020", after:=.Range("E1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'ThisWorkbook.Activate
    xlBook.Sheets(ShName).Range("A2").Value = ShName

    xlBook.Sheets(ShName).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 1)).Select

    'Sheets(ShName).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 1)).Select
End With

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlBook = ActiveWorkbook

Set sh = Sheets("Dealer_ID Check")

sh.Activate
Range("A1").Select
sh.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: That code will work if `xlBook.Sheets(ShName)` is the active sheet. Your `Cells` references are not qualified, so they assume `ActiveSheet` and if you try to use them inside of a range that refers to a different sheet, you will get an error. They do not automatically assume you are referring to the same sheet as you probably think they should.

Comment: Many issues here: You are using `Sheets("Data Check").Range("C3").Value` as both File name and Sheet name.  Is that deliberate? You don't `Copy` anything, so there's nothing to paste.  With `Find` you need to specify several other parameters.  Don't rely on `Select`, use references.  Beware implicit ActiveSheet references. Handle the case of `Find` returning `Nothing`. Handle File Not Found error. Is this code in Excel? If so, why create another instance?

Comment: braX, so you saying I would have to try active the sheet like ```xlBook.Sheets(ShName).Activate``` before referencing the firs and last row? Sorry I cannot check this right now. I will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: Chris Neilsen, Yes it is deliberate. I use ```Select``` to check if I referencing the right range and I know i do not copy paste as the code is not 100% finished because I stuck on this error, and when I sued copy it gives me the same error. NOt sure what other parameters I would have to use, the ``.Find``` is working as expected in this instance. Yes it is in EXCEL. and I anm not sure what you mean by "Handle the case of Find returning Nothing. Handle File Not Found error. Is this code in Excel? If so, why create another instance?"

Comment: I'm saying the code needs to be rewritten so that it does not depend on which sheet is active at the time. Your object references need to be fully qualified.

Comment: Shameless self linking for "What is meant by "Handle the case of Find returning Nothing. Handle File Not Found error"" 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211950/vba-how-to-handle-an-error-when-setting-a-variable/58212177#58212177

Comment: Re `Find` parameters, [from the help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)  _The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used_

Comment: @Michal when you reply to someones comment, use the `@user` syntax so they are notified.  I only came back here by change and saw your comment

Comment: @braX Thank you very much for your help and time. I will defo take use all your advises in my future projects!

Comment: @Michal you got that error because the method raising it can only be used on a object within the same `Excel.Application` instance than the `VBProject` hosting the code calling it, which in your case is not. I had the same issue with the `Worksheet.Copy` method where destination was in another `Excel.Application` than the `Worksheet` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting all the comments together, your code so far could be refactoed as

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetDataFromClosedBook()
    'copy data from closed workbook to active workbook

    Dim wbData As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook

    Dim wsDataCheck As Worksheet
    Dim wsDealerIDCheck As Worksheet
    Dim wsReports As Worksheet

    Dim ShName As String
    Dim PthName As String
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim rStartRow As Range, rEndRow As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook ' not prefered, better to be explicit

    Set wsDataCheck = wbDest.Worksheets("Data Check")

    'Path source Wokrbook
    PthName = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\EXCEL USEFUL DOSC\Missing Data Check New Process\Missing Data Reports\"
    FlName = wsDataCheck.Range("C3").Value
    ShName = wsDataCheck.Range("C3").Value

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(PthName & FlName & ".xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wbData Is Nothing Then
        ' File didn't open
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wsReports = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wsReports = wbData.Worksheets(ShName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wsReports Is Nothing Then
        ' No such sheet
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    With wsReports
        Set rStartRow = .Range("E:E").Find(What:="January-2020", After:=.Range("E1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set rEndRow = .Range("E:E").Find(What:="January-2020", After:=.Range("E1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        If rStartRow Is Nothing Or rEndRow Is Nothing Then
            ' Search term not found, What Now?
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If

        .Range("A2").Value = ShName

        Set rng = .Range(rStartRow, rEndRow)
' For debug purposes only
.Activate  ' the worksheet
rng.Select ' the range
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ' do you want to save the change you made to wbData?
    wbData.Close True ' or wbData.Save False

    Set wsDealerIDCheck = wbDest.Worksheets("Dealer_ID Check")

    '  continue ...

Exit Sub
CleanUp:
    If Not wbData Is Nothing Then wbData.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Chris, it is working as expected. Your help is much appreciated! The code is nice and easy to follow. It will defo help me in my future project. I also need to educate myself on how to be explicit with the workbooks etc but I will definitely learn a lot from the code you provided. I am self-learner and I know I am missing a lot of knowledge.... but I will get there slowly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The comments have pointed out the disassociation in your code many times.  Your code uses implicit and explicit references to worksheets without performing any of the necessary checks to prevent errors.

The commenters we're being polite and didn't use strong terms, but I am not polite: ***`ActiveSheet` is not what you think it is.***

What you think `ActiveSheet` is during design is practically never guaranteed to be `ActiveSheet` during run time.  There are certainly times when they are but such certainties are rare unless you make the effort to code then into reality.  All other times you should explicitly reference your ranges.  Consider it a life saving skill

Let's assume you set a pointer to a workbook and you open it, whatever sheet it opens to becomes the `ActiveSheet`.  Typically this is the sheet that was last viewed when the workbook was saved, but that is by no means guaranteed.

What is even less guaranteed, is your assumption that it will open to the "Data Check" sheet.

You can read from and write to the "Data Check" sheet all day long without caring if it is the `ActiveSheet` or not, but you can only `Select` a cell on it when it is the `ActiveSheet`.

The worksheet variable`ShName` is set to the "Data Check" worksheet.  At no point have you validated `ShName` as the `ActiveSheet`, but `ShName` must be the `ActiveSheet` to prevent an error on this line:

```
xlBook.Sheets(ShName).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 1)).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had this error in word but as was pointed out "ActiveDocument" was the issue even though I only had one word application open. By changing to wdApp.ActiveDocument it resolved it. wdApp being my word.application object.